# Host Git Repository via port 80

Tags: git, port, gitstack

I have installed GitStack for Windows, which says I must use `git clone [ip/domain]/myproject.git`

However, I'm in a firewalled environment where port 9418 is blocked. Port 443 and 22 also seem to be blocked. I'm hoping to get permission to open them up soon.

But meanwhile, **is there a way I can utilize port 80?** Perhaps even setup a website at a specific url that transfers the git protocols through port 80?

I'm really not sure why Git has options for automatically using 443 and 9418, but not port 80???

That way someone on my network can connect to that url, and it will just kinda proxy the git protocol?

I've tried (showing that the port is blocked):

```
curl http://[myip]:9418
exit code (7) no error.
```

I've tried using the following but I don't think port 443 is working:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

I can't even connect to my own computer with port 9418 on this network:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9418 -v

* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 9418 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x22e02a8
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x22e02a8) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:9418; No error
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:9418; No error
```

**EDITTTTT: Ok so turns out, if you use git clone http://[IP]:80/project.git it will utilize port 80.**

Answer (score 1):

turns out, if you use `git clone http://[IP]:80/project.git` it will utilize port 80. I guess I was trying to use the domain and so it wasn't resolving the IP and I assumed it was because port 80 doesn't work only git:// (9418) or SSH (22) or HTTPS (443).